# Python regex not working

Tags: python, regex

I am using the following code:

```
downloadlink = re.findall("http://uploadir.com/u/(.*)\b", str(downloadhtml))
```

However, when I pass it the following string:

```
<input type="text" value="http://uploadir.com/u/bb41c5b3" />
```

It finds nothing, when I'm expecting it to find: `http://uploadir.com/u/bb41c5b3`. What am I doing wrong?

I have tested the regex using http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ and it seems to be correct. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> html = '<input type="text" value="http://uploadir.com/u/bb41c5b3" />';
>>> regex = r'http://uploadir.com/u/([^"]+)'
>>> link = re.findall(regex, html)
>>> link
['bb41c5b3']
>>>
```

Comment: You genius! Thank so much! Have to wait 5 minutes, to mark as fixed >.>

Answer (score 13):

Get in the habit of making all regex patterns with raw strings:

```
In [16]: re.findall("http://uploadir.com/u/(.*)\b", '<input type="text" value="http://uploadir.com/u/bb41c5b3" />')
Out[16]: []

In [17]: re.findall(r"http://uploadir.com/u/(.*)\b", '<input type="text" value="http://uploadir.com/u/bb41c5b3" />')
Out[17]: ['bb41c5b3']
```

The difference is due to `\b` being [interpreted differently](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals):

```
In [18]: '\b'
Out[18]: '\x08'

In [19]: r'\b'
Out[19]: '\\b'
```

`'\b'` is an ASCII Backspace, while `r'\b'` is a string composed of the two characters, a backslash and a b.

Comment: Your lines are identical, maybe there's an extra `r` on the first line?

Comment: @Mark E: Thank you. Corrected.

Comment: +1 for emphasizing the importance of raw strings. A regex gets messy fast  with all those extra bashslashes

Comment: Thanks for explaining the importance of 'r'.

Comment: This just solved my problem, thanks so much!